# How to use Proxifier for VMware?

Tags: vmware

I want to use VMware with Proxifier. I have tried Virtrualbox NAT-network, it works fine. However, VMware NAT-network doesn't work. How do I make it work?

Comment: Please re-phrase your question so it is actually a question.

Comment: @Richie086 It's clear that he's asking how to make it work. Regardless, I edited it for him

Comment: @chipperyman573 tk you very much !! :D

Comment: Try bridged mode networking in VMWare to see if that helps..